# Replace lines between patterns with single string

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I've got this file I would like to work on :

```
{'ID1': {'Zero': u'value',
               'One': 'value',
               'Two': 'value',
               'Three': 'value',
               'Four': 'value'},
 'ID2': {'Zero': u'alue',
               'One': 'value',
               'Two': 'value',
               'Three': 'value',
               'Four': 'value'})
```

I've got this sed liner to get single properties :

```
sed -n '/ID1.*{/,/}/p' file
```

That will give me this :

```
{'ID1': {'Zero': u'value',
               'One': 'value',
               'Two': 'value',
               'Three': 'value',
               'Four': 'value'}
```

What I would like to do is to replace that output with a STRING

Can't figure it out how.

Comment: 1) is this json? 2) paste the desired output

Comment: Use an appropriate `JSON` parsing tool like `jq`

Comment: My desired output is any string like "#### DELETED ENTRY ####"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `p` with `{/}/!d;s/.*/STRING/p}`

Rather than print every matching line:

- `/}/!d` delete lines not containing `}`.  (*Not* containing the END pattern of the range)
- `s/.*/STRING/p` replace the entire line with STRING
- Finally, *after* the manipulations above: `p` to print anything else outside the range

Full command, the the manipulation inside the range between the bold braces:

> `sed -n '/ID1.*{/,/}/`**`{`**`/}/!d;s/.*/STRING/p`**`}`**`;p' file`

Output:

```
STRING 
 'ID2': {'Zero': u'alue',
               'One': 'value',
               'Two': 'value',
               'Three': 'value',
               'Four': 'value'})
```

You are aware, I'm sure, that this depends quite a lot on the formatting of your JSON... you can't have any nested `{}`. It's a worthwhile sed question, though, because trying to use the `i` command to insert gets stupid, with line clunky line continuations.

Comment: What i want is to replace the entire :

{'ID1': {'Zero': u'value',
               'One': 'value',
               'Two': 'value',
               'Three': 'value',
               'Four': 'value'}

With "STRING" 

Thanks.

Comment: @user3329334 - your original code did not print other lines outside the range.   I added a `;p` after the code above